# What databases and versions are supported by Flyway 5.2.4 and older versions

Tags: flyway

Where can I find the flyway documentations for older versions? The flyway website only provides the supported databases for flyway 6 and 7. But we're still using SQL Server 2012, Oracle 11g etc, we would like to find a flyway community version which could support these old databases and versions.

Comment: A list of supported DBs is in their documentation https://flywaydb.org/documentation/

Comment: @blurfus please read my question before rushing to answer. The link you provided only has the information for flyway 6 & 7. It doesn't have the information of older flyway versions, which was what I am asking.

Comment: My bad, I missed the part where you were looking specifically for docs for the 5.2.4 version

Answer (score 0):

The website flywaydb.org shows documentation for supported versions, and 5.2.4 is now quite elderly and out of formal support. We would recommend you use the latest version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But we don't really need the formal support from flyway team. As with other open source libraries, we take our own risk to use the community edition of flyway, but not expecting the documents of old versions were intentionally removed. This is not a foreseeable risk as other open source libraries.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

This restriction is no longer in place from Flyway version 10 (October 2023). We have updated Flyway so that it works with ALL supported database versions, so if you upgrade to version 10 you can access all supported versions.

The community version of Flyway now works with All versions.

You can access the latest download from https://www.red-gate.com/products/flyway/community/download/